# How do I get this elements in my bootstrap5 navbar?

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

This is my current navbar with the logo in the middle centered but now I need to add a searbar and some icons like this: [ideal navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQIiD.png)

[My current navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQbD9.png)

```
<header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md ">
        <div id="nav" class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand d-md-none" href="index.html">
                <img src="relogo.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="produkte.html">PRODUKTE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ANBIETER</a>
                    </li>
                    <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="index.html">
                        <img src="relogo.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ÜBER UNS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

adding In the last line of the navbar but now the logo isn't centered anymore and the icons are below
[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlLP6.png)
`<li> <form class="d-flex"> <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"> </form> </li>`

Answer (score 0):

You should make position of searchbar to absolute related to navbar.

```css
#nav-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#nav-searchbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav-searchbar {
    top: 15px;
    left: 80px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="nav-header" class="navbar navbar-expand-md d-flex items-center">
      <div id="nav" class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-md-none" href="index.html">
          <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/18/200/200.jpg?hmac=naWL3P7tSw9NeN2OXqD0XhBgnBko_h5B-Z3UdUVLFcU" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="produkte.html">PRODUKTE</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ANBIETER</a>
            </li>
            <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="index.html">
              <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/18/200/200.jpg?hmac=naWL3P7tSw9NeN2OXqD0XhBgnBko_h5B-Z3UdUVLFcU" alt="">
            </a>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ÜBER UNS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-searchbar">
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This could work, but there's no logo. Tip: Use [a placeholder image](https://picsum.photos/). When the navbar collapses the searchbar is part of the hidden menu. There is enough room for it in the navbar.

Comment: You can insert image at `<img src="relogo.png" alt="">`.

Comment: Or, could you leave your image url?

Comment: I tried to suggest that you could mimic the logo image with a placeholder, to make it look better.

Comment: @ KIKO, I updated code for your requirement. Please try again

Comment: One final thing to make it perfect: Your searchbar is now: `width: 70%;`, which means the space between it and the hamburger menu varies. You can solve this by using: `width: calc(100% - 60px);`. Whereby the `60px` determine the space between the two.

Comment: Good job! I fixed something a little.